# Modifying swiper initialization code

Tags: jquery

I am using idangerous swiper.js for menu display 
My requirement was to move the clicked elemnet on the menu  to the center of the menu .

I could able to achive this using this

```
$(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function() {
  var str = $(this).text();
  var str2 = $("#center").text();
  $(this).removeClass('swiper-slide-active');
  $('.swiper-slide').removeClass('swiper-slide-active');
  $(this).children().text(str2);
  $("#center").children().text(str);
  $("#center").addClass('swiper-slide-active');
  var menuclickedelement = $("#center").children().text();
});


var T1categories = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE" , "FOUR" , "FIVE"];
createhorizontaltab(T1categories);
function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
  var categoryArr = categories;
  var favoriteresultag = '';
  var centervalue = Math.floor(categoryArr.length / 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr.length; i++) {
    if (i != centervalue) {
      favoriteresultag += '<div class="swiper-slide"><span>' + categoryArr[i] + '</span></div>';
    } else {
      favoriteresultag += '<div class="swiper-slide" id="center"><span>' + categoryArr[i] + '</span></div>';
    }
  }
  $("#swipecontainer").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");
  $("#swipecontainer .swiper-slide").eq(centervalue).trigger("click");

  // callmenuInit();  
}
```

This code is only working if i **comment** out the **callmenuInit()**;

If i **uncomment** this code , its not working .

could you please let me know how to resolve this

http://jsfiddle.net/nx33jez6/1/

Please excuse if this question is not related to jquery .

This is my callmenuinit

```
  function callmenuInit() {
        //Init Navigation
        var nav = $('.swiper-nav').swiper({
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                freeMode: true,
                freeModeFluid: true,
                onSlideClick: function(nav) {
                    pages.swipeTo(nav.clickedSlideIndex)
                }
            })
            //Function to Fix Pages Height
        function fixPagesHeight() {
            $('.swiper-pages').css({
                height: $(window).height() - nav.height

            })
        }
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            fixPagesHeight()
        })
        fixPagesHeight();
            //Init Pages
        var pages = $('.swiper-pages').swiper()
            //Scroll Containers
        $('.scroll-container').each(function() {
                $(this).swiper({
                    mode: 'vertical',
                    scrollContainer: true,
                    mousewheelControl: true,
                    scrollbar: {
                        container: $(this).find('.swiper-scrollbar')[0]
                    }
                })
            })
            //Gallery
        var swiperGallery = $('.swiper-gallery').swiper({
            mode: 'vertical',
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            freeMode: true,
            freeModeFluid: true,
            scrollbar: {
                container: $('.swiper-gallery .swiper-scrollbar')[0]
            }
        })
        swiperGallery.reInit()
    }
```

Comment: How exactly "it's not working"? Any errors in JS console?

Comment: I am getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined under console .

Comment: *> Uncaught TypeError* What line on?

Comment: ok sorry , un console i get at this line swiper.min.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Comment: Show your `callmenuInit` function

Comment: I edited my question and posted that .

Answer (score 2):

1)

`$(this).find('.swiper-scrollbar')[0]` is undefined. `<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>` was commented so I uncommented it.

2)

[Swiper API](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api) says that `scrollbar` option is String or HTML element. But you set it as an Object. It should be like `scrollbar: $(this).find('.swiper-scrollbar')[0]`

3)

There is no `.swiper-gallery` element so `var swiperGallery = $('.swiper-gallery').swiper({` cannot be initialized.

So now there is only `TypeError: swiperGallery is undefined` exception raised.

http://jsfiddle.net/nx33jez6/2/